# Absolute path required?

Tags: c#, path

Usually when I build an application in C# which can digest command line parameters, if these parameters are file paths strings, I could choose to use relative paths as well as absolute paths to refer to a specific file on my computer and use it in the program.

In my last project, my application does not work if I give it a relative path from the command prompt. But in debug mode in VS 2010, it digests relative paths. From the command prompt it requires an absolute path to work.

Comment: Please supply some detail - maybe even some code.

Comment: Removed tags 'absolute' and 'relative' as they were too specific

Comment: I really don't know what code I could give you guys, as it is very basic sing reading from the command line... args[0] being the path of the file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the working directory. See: [Directory.SetCurrentDirectory Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.setcurrentdirectory.aspx)

**Example**:

`System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory( System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory );`

In a debug build the Current Directory is set to debug\bin by default.

Specifies the working directory of the program being debugged. In Visual C#, the working directory is the directory the application is launched from \bin\debug by default.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kf0yb05.aspx

You can also retrieve the assembly's path using **Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()** or **Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()** and then using either the Location property or the CodeBase property.

Answer (score 2):

You can turn the relative path into an absolute paths yourself, like this:

```
if (!Path.IsPathRooted(path))
    path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\\" + path;
```

Or change the current directory to the executable path:

```
string exePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(exePath);
```